# bash script required lines from multiple files bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, scripting

I need a shell script to be designed to print lines in a pattern from three files.

```
file1.txt, file2.txt,file3.txt
```

I need the output to be

```
line1 of file1.txt
line2 of file1.txt
line1 of file2.txt
line2 of file2.txt
line1 of file3.txt
line2 of file3.txt
line3 of file1.txt
line4 of file1.txt
line3 of file2.txt
line4 of file2.txt
line3 of file3.txt
line4 of file3.txt

...
```

How can we get this in a shell script?
Also it should print only the non-blank lines.

Comment: How big are these files? Would it be reasonable to fit them all in memory and loop through the lines?

Comment: Do the files all have the same number of lines? If not, what should happen when we reach a line number that doesn't exist in every file?

Comment: @TomFenech:Yes , but I dont have idea about the length of the files.

Comment: @Aaronconsider all the files have equal length

Comment: Seems like a bit of a contradiction (are they too long or not?). What happens if the files are different lengths? [Edit] your question to show a concrete example of your input and desired output. It would also be good if you made an attempt at solving your problem yourself.

Comment: @TomFenech: If the length of the files are not equal, we will print the line pattern required of the remaining files. I tried but unable to make it the pattern required.

Comment: If lines 3 and 4 of file 2 are  empty, is the output `...line3/4 file1; line3/4 file3...` or `...line3/4 file1; line5/6 file2; line3/4 file3...` or something else? Provide concise, testable sample input and expected output that includes your rainy day cases.

Comment: if line 1 of file1 is blank, should we just print line 2 from file1 before movind to file2, or print lines 2 and 3?

Comment: That does not answer my question.

Comment: @glennjackman yes you are right. I need exactly that

Comment: still not an answer. I am asking you an "A" or "B" question, and you are answering "yes". This is what you need to do: show us 3 sample files, that include blank lines, and then show us the output you want. Specifying your requirements clearly and unambiguously is an important skill to learn.

Comment: @glennjackman if line1 of file1 is blank, I need not print that line instead go ahead and check line2 of file1, if that is also blank go ahead to the file2 and repeat the same thing till file3

Answer (score 3):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -e 'open $FH[ @FH ], "<", $_ or die $! for @ARGV;
         while (grep !eof $_, @FH) {
             for my $fh (@FH) {
                 print scalar <$fh> for 1, 2;
             }
         }' -- file*.txt
```

It keeps all the files opened at the same time (the @FH array contains the filehandles). While at least one hasn't ended yet, it prints two lines from each.

Answer (score 2):

What about the following script, which accepts the files as parameters :

```
TOTAL_LINES=$(wc -l < "$1")
for n in $(seq 1 2 $TOTAL_LINES); do
  for file in "$@"; do
    sed -n "$n{p;n;p}" $file
  done
done
```

I've considered all files had the same number of lines as suggested in the comments, but it will also work when it's not the case provided you pass the longest file as first parameter.

A little explanation on parts of the script you're the less likely to know :

- `seq` will generate a sequence of numbers `for` will iterate over. It's syntax is `seq from increment upTo` and it's used instead of the `{from..upTo..increment}` syntax which doesn't accept variables
- `$@` is an array of the parameters passed to the script
- `sed -n "$n{p;n;p}"` is a `sed` command that won't display the text by default, but will execute `p`, `n` and `p` again for the line `$n` ; `p` prints the current line, `n` goes to the next line

Answer (score 2):

Consider four similar input files:

```
$ cat file1.txt
line1 of file1.txt
line2 of file1.txt
line3 of file1.txt
line4 of file1.txt
```

We create `printer.sh` as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
LINES=2 # Configure this to set the number of consecutive lines per file

MAX_HANDLE=3
# Create descriptors 3,4,... for filename1,filename2....
for var in "$@"
do
      eval exec "$MAX_HANDLE"'<"$var"'
      ((MAX_HANDLE++))
done

# Start infinite loop
while :
do
  # First descriptor is 3
  COUNTER=3

  # Loop over all open file descriptors from 3 to MAX_HANDLE - 1
  while [  $COUNTER -lt $MAX_HANDLE ]; do
    # Read $LINES lines from the open file descriptor
    LINE_COUNTER=0
    while [  $LINE_COUNTER -lt $LINES ]; do
      read -r line <&"$COUNTER" || DONE=true
      if [[ "$DONE" = true ]]; then
        exit
      fi


      # Print the line that was read
      echo "$line"
      ((LINE_COUNTER++))
    done
    ((COUNTER++))
  done
done
```

On executing this, the input parameters are each added to a new handle and read `$LINES` lines at a time (in this case 2 lines at a time). This only works for identical length files as OP posited.

```
$ ./printer.sh file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt
line1 of file1.txt
line2 of file1.txt
line1 of file2.txt
line2 of file2.txt
line1 of file3.txt
line2 of file3.txt
line1 of file4.txt
line2 of file4.txt
line3 of file1.txt
line4 of file1.txt
line3 of file2.txt
line4 of file2.txt
line3 of file3.txt
line4 of file3.txt
line3 of file4.txt
line4 of file4.txt
```

Comment: if line1 of file1 is blank, I need not print that line instead go ahead and check line2 of file1, if that is also blank go ahead to the file2 and repeat the same thing till file3..How can we do this?

Comment: I've edited the check to do what you asked for. Now it reads till EOF @deeps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `paste` with `awk` to get your output:

```
paste -d $'\01' file[123].txt |
awk -F '\01' 'NR%2{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[i]=$i; next} 
    {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print a[i] ORS $i}'

line1 of file1.txt
line2 of file1.txt
line1 of file2.txt
line2 of file2.txt
line1 of file3.txt
line2 of file3.txt
line3 of file1.txt
line4 of file1.txt
line3 of file2.txt
line4 of file2.txt
line3 of file3.txt
line4 of file3.txt
```

- Using `paste` we create side-by-side `control-A` (ASCII 1) delimited output
- Using `awk` with field separator as `control-A` we output 2 lines from each column

Comment: I've added a brief explanation. I can answer any specific question you have. If you run `paste -d $'\01' file[123].txt | cat -vte` you will see output from `paste` to get better understanding of next awk command

Comment: How can I generalise that statement suppose I require 3 lines instead of 2 lines per file and how can I avoid printing if the lines contain blank lines?
Like if line1 of file1 is blank, I need not print that line instead go ahead and check line2 of file1, if that is also blank go ahead to the file2 and repeat the same thing till file3

Comment: If you edit your question and show a sample of your modified inputs with expected output then I can certainly modify this answer.

Answer (score 2):

lots of answers. This one is awk

create the test files

```
for f in file{1,2,3}.txt; do rm $f; for n in {1,2,3,4}; do echo "line $n of file $f" >> $f; done; done
```

and the awk program

```
awk '
    FNR == 1 && NR>1 {
        exit # exit after completing the first file
    }
    {
        # print 2 lines from the first file
        if (NF) print
        getline; if (NF) print
        # print 2 lines from each other file
        for (i=2; i<ARGC; i++) {
            getline < ARGV[i]; if (NF) print
            getline < ARGV[i]; if (NF) print
        }
    }
' file{1,2,3}.txt
```

The `if (NF) print` lines exclude blank lines since the number of whitespace-separated fields will be zero.

```
line 1 of file file1.txt
line 2 of file file1.txt
line 1 of file file2.txt
line 2 of file file2.txt
line 1 of file file3.txt
line 2 of file file3.txt
line 3 of file file1.txt
line 4 of file file1.txt
line 3 of file file2.txt
line 4 of file file2.txt
line 3 of file file3.txt
line 4 of file file3.txt
```

Comment: Can you please suggest how can we do the same in python?
all files are non of same length.
if line1 of file1 is blank, I need not print that line instead go ahead and check line2 of file1, if that is also blank go ahead to the file2 and repeat the same thing till file3.
Could we generalise the number of lines to be printed and the number 
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most efficient approach, but this will work, assuming that you have all your files in $files, and $total_lines contains the number of lines in each file:

```
for line in $(seq 1 $total_lines)
do
    for file in $files
    do
        sed '/^$/d' $file | sed $line'!d'
    done
done
```

sed '/^$/d' removes all the empty lines from the stream;

sed $line'!d' prints out the line corresponding to $line

Comment: While it was not stated explicitely, I think OP wants to display the lines two by two, as in his example output.

Answer (score 1):

Using paste and awk.

```
$ cat test.sh 
paste -d '|' file* | awk -F\| '{
    if(NR % 2 == 1) {
        file1 = $1; 
        file2 = $2; 
        file3 = $3; 
    } else {
        file1 = file1 "\n" $1; 
        file2 = file2 "\n" $2; 
        file3 = file3 "\n" $3; 
        print file1;
        print file2;
        print file3;
    }
}'
```

Because all files have same length, we can pasted all files first and printed when row number is even.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind creating intermediate/temporary files, [split(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html) which is part of *coreutils* of every Linux distribution might be handy:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Split files every 2 lines using a numeric suffix 
for f in file*.txt; do
    split -d -l 2 "${f}" "${f}"split
done

# Reverse intermediate file names, so we can glob them in numeric order 
for f in file*split*; do
    mv "${f}" "reversed$(echo ${f}|rev)"
done

cat reversed* && rm reversed*
```